# how to restore Firefox not the last "Restore Previous Session" pages

Tags: session, firefox

I would like to restore not the last "Restore Previous Session".

1. Open firefox (v78.0) with few tabs: aaa.com, bbb.com.
2. Close Firefox.
3. Open Firefox, open few tabs, ccc.com, ddd.com.
4. Close Firefox.
5. Open Firefox. How to get those tabs aaa.com, bbb.com from "Restore Previous Session"?

Answer (score 12):

I went to the address bar of Firefox, typed `about:support` and saw which is the profile folder of Firefox.

I figured out that some versions of Firefox create a
`c:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\j1hcxbyk.default-release\sessionstore.jsonlz4` file when Firefox is closed.

I also found a copy of a session file
`c:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\j1hcxbyk.default-release\sessionstore-backups\upgrade.jsonlz4-20200630195452`

So, I:

1. stopped Firefox,
2. made a back-up copy of the profile folder,
3. replaced `sessionstore.jsonlz4` (or copied there if that file didn't exist) with `upgrade.jsonlz4-20200630195452`,
4. started Firefox,
5. restored the previous session with: Menu->History->Restore Previous Session,
6. checked that the old session, with my tabs, was restored.

Note: I chose `upgrade.jsonlz4-20200630195452` because it was created in the same day, when I closed Firefox with all my tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and Firefox wouldn't read the *.jsonlz4 files properly, so I coded a little script to extract the URLS stored inside *.jsonlz4 files:
https://github.com/matthieuheitz/recover-firefox-session
Some people use this tool: https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html, but it didn't work for me as the *.jsonlz4 files were very large (> 50MB), and the website just lags forever.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I faced the same issue of missing tabs when I restored the correct system date from some earlier date. After scouring the internet, I got the following tip to restore the firefox tabs back from saved sessions. My PC runs Microsoft Windows 10 Home with Firefox version 91.0.

Reference: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1314940
"At startup, Firefox usually will look first for `sessionstore.jsonlz4` at the main level of your profile folder and if it finds it, use its contents to create `recovery.jsonlz4` -- if you restore automatically -- or `previous.jsonlz4` -- if you do not restore automatically. So you could try replacing that file if you haven't already (as well as recovery.jsonlz4)".

1. Close the firefox browser.
2. Open `%AppData%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles folder`
3. Select the latest folder that contains .default in it.
4. Open `sessionstore-backups` folder. Now your path would be something like `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\13dn9aq1.default-1473265690957-1560267471460\sessionstore-backups`
5. Locate files with `upgrade.jsonlz4-` prefix and select the one which you think probably would contain your tabs.
6. Keep the original one untouched. Create a copy of it and rename it to `sessionstore.jsonlz4`
7. Copy the sessionstore.jsonlz4 file. Locate the `sessionstore.jsonlz4` file in the folder one level down: `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\13dn9aq1.default-1473265690957-1560267471460\` and replace it with the `sessionstore.jsonlz4` file just copied.
8. Now you can open Firefox and you will get all your old tabs from the restored session.

The folder **.default.** can be located as follows also,

- Type "about:profiles" in firefox and press enter
- Click "Open Folder " next to Root Directory path

Comment: [Chris Wynter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17136243) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543982) saying "Thanks Vinu, that did it! I would suggest a rewording of 7: Copy the sessionstore.jsonlz4 file. Locate the sessionstore.jsonlz4 file in the folder one level down: %AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\13dn9aq1.default-1473265690957-1560267471460\ and replace it with the sessionstore.jsonlz4 file just copied. Thanks!"

Answer (score 1):

Recent Firefox version (version 96 this time, or at least the Linux one) doesn't have `sessionstore.jsonlz4` in the root of the profile, so the other advices does not seem to work.

Firefox nightly upgrades a lot, so I have a very good chance to have FF restarted and lose all the session with no "restore session" available at all.

The solution (for me at least) was

- stop Firefox
- go to session backup directory at `~/.mozilla/firefox/<session_name>/sessionstore-backups/`
- copy any old file over `recovery.jsonlz4` (say, `cp upgrade.jsonlz4-20211112213406 upgrade.jsonlz4-20211112213406`)
- start firefox, and let it automagically restore th old session

It seems firefox only stores *only the last* `previous.jsonlz4` there apart from upgrades, so it may be useful to ask `cron` to make periodical backups of `recovery.jsonlz4` or similar.